# Using \def variables computed by \FPeval within tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fp

Hello there I am an absoulute beginner.

I took some tikz template for drawing nerual nets and tried to modify it so I can change the number of layers automatically, but it yields strange errors.

I am using these packages and have no idea if it matters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion]{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
```

I came up with a following macro in a separate .sty file:

```
\newcommand{\mln}[3]{
    \def\layersep{#1}
    \def\inpneuroncount{#2}
    \def\hidneuroncount{#3}

    \FPeval{result}{clip((\hidneuroncount-\inpneuroncount)/2)}
    \def\nodeoffset{yshift=\result cm}
    \nodeoffset

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
        \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=3pt]
        \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=15pt,inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
        \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
        \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
        \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\inpneuroncount}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

        % Draw the hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
            \path[\nodeoffset]
                node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

        % Draw the output layer node
        \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-1] (O) {};

        % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
        % hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,\inpneuroncount}
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
                \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

        % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
        \foreach \source in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
            \path (H-\source) edge (O);

        % Annotate the layers
        \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
        \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
        \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % End of code
}
```

What I am trying to do rn, is to make the yshift of the hidden layer to be equal to the half of the difference between number of input neurons and hidden layer neurons. I cretaed a variable \nodeoffset, which after usage clearly renders the text "yshift=0.5cm" when u use \mln{2.5cm}{2}{3}

When I try to use it in the part

```
% Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
        \path[\nodeoffset]
```

it yelds error like "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/yshift=0.5cm' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

How do I get the parameter there correctly?

Comment: Welcome! You *can* make it work by using `\path[style/.expanded=\nodeoffset]...`. However, I'd rather replace `\def\nodeoffset{yshift=\result cm}` by `\tikzset{my node offset/.style={yshift=\result cm}}` and then use `\path[my node offset] ... ` instead of `\path[\nodeoffset]`. BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: I also advise against using a 3-argument macro in the way you do. Rather, you might want to use pgf keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing a so-called expansion issue. Ti*k*Z does not fully expand the macro `\nodeoffset`. You can make it expand by replacing

```
\path[\nodeoffset] node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};
```

by

```
\path[style/.expanded=\nodeoffset] node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand{\mln}[3]{
    \def\layersep{#1}
    \def\inpneuroncount{#2}
    \def\hidneuroncount{#3}

    \FPeval{result}{clip((\hidneuroncount-\inpneuroncount)/2)}
    \def\nodeoffset{yshift=\result cm}
    \nodeoffset

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
        \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=3pt]
        \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=15pt,inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
        \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
        \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
        \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\inpneuroncount}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

        % Draw the hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
            \path[style/.expanded=\nodeoffset]
                node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

        % Draw the output layer node
        \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-1] (O) {};

        % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
        % hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,\inpneuroncount}
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
                \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

        % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
        \foreach \source in {1,...,\hidneuroncount}
            \path (H-\source) edge (O);

        % Annotate the layers
        \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
        \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
        \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % End of code
}
\begin{document}
\mln{8em}{5}{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would like to suggest some modifications/improvements.

1. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, use the corresponding `\tikzset` syntax (see below) instead.
2. You actually do not need `fp` here.
3. Use `positioning`.
4. The `\def`s in the beginning do not really seem to have a purpose.

There are many more things that one may change, but this is a partly modified version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\mln}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=#1]
        \tikzset{every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=3pt},
          neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=15pt,inner
            sep=0pt},
          input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
          output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
          hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
          annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
        my offset/.style={yshift={((#3-#2)/2)*1cm}}}
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=diag]
          % Draw the input layer nodes
          \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,#2}
          % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
              \node[input neuron, pin={[alias=auxI]left:Input \#\y}] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

          % Draw the hidden layer nodes
          \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,#3}
              {\path[my offset]
                  node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (#1,-\y cm) {};}

          % Draw the output layer node
          \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->},alias=auxO]right:Output}, right=of H-1] (O) {};

          % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
          % hidden layer.
          \foreach \source in {1,...,#2}
              \foreach \dest in {1,...,#3}
                  \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

          % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
          \foreach \source in {1,...,#3}
              \path (H-\source) edge (O);
        \end{scope}
        % Annotate the layers
        \path ([yshift=1ex]diag.north-|H-1.center) node[anchor=south,annot] (hl) {Hidden layer};
        \path ([yshift=1ex]diag.north-|auxI.west) node[anchor=south west,annot]  {Input layer};
        \path ([yshift=1ex]diag.north-|auxO.east) node[anchor=south east,annot]  {Output layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % End of code
}
\begin{document}
\mln{8em}{5}{4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't thought of `style/.expanded=` before.  Good one!

Comment: But yes, the proper way to do things is to use keys and values instead of macros (which is part of the reason why I removed `\coord` from `let`).

Comment: I'm actually planning to come your way in these terms with a new [`reflection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) library which stores all the information about a point in pgfkeys.  That would also replace `\tikz@dcl@coord@<x>` by `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/reflection/<x>/declared coordinate}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Looking forward to seeing this library!

Comment: The OP is not using xfp (which I would naturally prefer) but fp.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, you are right.